# cgpdftraster quit unexpectedly: Report sent to apple; just after installing Sierra ; canon 640 will not print from rear tray

Tags: imac, macos

Canon 640 will not load & print from rear tray after installing Serria?

Answer (score 1):

From [Cannon KB : Canon PIXMA MP640](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp640.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=macOS%2010.12%20(Sierra))

> Please Note: There are currently no macOS 10.12 Sierra printer drivers available for PIXMA products. This issue is being investigated and we hope to have these drivers available soon.

I guess you'll either have to wait, or go back to El Capitan.

It's always wise to check compatibility for mission-critical apps & devices before jumping to a new OS.